# Strange results of typeof operator on DOM node element (angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, typeof, jqlite

I have a question regarding `typeof` DOM node.

Is that ok that Safari 5.1.7 on Windows return "function"?

```
typeof document.getElementsByTagName('head') === "function",
```

but on chrome

```
typeof document.getElementsByTagName('head') === "object"
```

This causes Angular 1 to break down on getting "jqLite" element:

```
jqLite(document.getElementsByTagName('head')) === Object[0]
```

as there are check in angular.js 1.6.1:

```
function JQLite(element) {
  //...
  if (argIsString) {
    jqLiteAddNodes(this, jqLiteParseHTML(element));
  } else if (isFunction(element)) {
    //it returns true
    jqLiteReady(element);
  } else {
    jqLiteAddNodes(this, element);
  }
```

So basically my question is it suppose that `isFunction` called with dom element parameter return true? Is it Safari bug or not?

Comment: Considering Safari for Windows was discontinued quite a long time ago, I'm guessing they won't fix it, if it is a bug.

Comment: Safari was discontinued on Windows five years ago. Are there people still using it?

Comment: I used Safari for Windows for testing in very rear cases.